# How to use RwLocks without scoped?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to share a [RwLock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) amongst several threads without using scoped threads but I can't figure out how to get the lifetimes correct. I assume that this is possible (what's the point of RwLocks otherwise?) but I can't find any examples of it.

Here is a toy example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Any advice would be appreciated.
[rust playpen for this code](http://is.gd/hdWCzr)

```
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;

struct Stuff {
    x: i32
}

fn main() {
    let mut stuff = Stuff{x: 5};
    helper(&mut stuff);
    println!("done");
}

fn helper(stuff: &mut Stuff){
    let rwlock = RwLock::new(stuff);
    let arc = Arc::new(rwlock);
    let local_arc = arc.clone();
    for _ in 0..10{
        let my_rwlock = arc.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let reader = my_rwlock.read().unwrap();
            // do some stuff
        });
    }
    let mut writer = local_arc.write().unwrap();
    writer.x += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&mut` references are not safe to send to a non-scoped thread, because the thread may still run after the referenced data has been deallocated. Furthermore, after `helper` returns, the main thread would still be able to mutate `stuff`, and the spawned thread would also be able to mutate `stuff` indirectly, which is not allowed in Rust (there can only be one mutable alias for a variable).

Instead, the `RwLock` should own the data, rather than borrow it. This means `helper` should receive a `Stuff` rather than a `&mut Stuff`.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;

struct Stuff {
    x: i32
}

fn main() {
    let mut stuff = Stuff{x: 5};
    helper(stuff);
    println!("done");
}

fn helper(stuff: Stuff){
    let rwlock = RwLock::new(stuff);
    let arc = Arc::new(rwlock);
    let local_arc = arc.clone();
    for _ in 0..10{
        let my_rwlock = arc.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let reader = my_rwlock.read().unwrap();
            // do some stuff
        });
    }
    let mut writer = local_arc.write().unwrap();
    writer.x += 1;
}
```